# Minimum possible distance between $n$ grid points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, optimization, analytic-geometry

We are given a grid and a set $S$ of $n$ points on it (i.e points in the plane with integer coordinates). 
 We define the diamatar $diam(S)$ of $S$ to be the maximum possible distance between two points in $S$, that is, $diam(S) = \max\{distance(a, b):a,b \in S \}$. 
 What is the minimal possible value of $diam(S)$ for general $n$? Is there a closed formula, in terms of $n$? 
 For example, for $n=1$ the answer is $0$. For $n=2$ the answer is $1$ and for $n=5$ the answer is $2$. 
I would also like to know closed formulas for special cases, for example, for the case where $n$ is a perfect sqaure.

Comment: If instead of $n$ points, you had to draw a shape of area $n$ with the minimal perimeter - what shape would that be?

Comment: I don't believe there is a closed formula for general $n$, but there is an asymptotic formula.

Comment: @Kolja I guess a rectangle

Comment: The answer is $2$ for $n=5$? Not $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer You can take for example the points to be $(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (1,1), (1, -1)$

Comment: @Kolja Is there a formula for the case where $n$ is a perfect square? I think the best option would be to take a square.

Comment: Not really a square, but that's a close enough guess. It is a well known shape (even though the proof that such a shape is optimal is non-trivial). Think about it a bit more, try to draw it for example.

Answer (score 1):

A circle is clearly a sensible shape to consider for a 'close-packing' of integer points. For a circle of given radius $r$, (diameter $2r$), the numbers of points can easily be calculated. The solutions for small integer values of $r$ are given in A000328 - OEIS.

For example the value of $5$, as you've already determined, is given for $r=1$  and $13$ is the value for $r=2$.

If you've not already found it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem is also a site you should visit. In particular it gives an approximate relation between the diameter, $d$,
and $n$.

$$\pi d^2\approx 4n.$$

As you will see the general problem is difficult, without precise formulae.

Comment: Do you know if for $n = N^2$ the best option is to take an $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ square of grid points?

Comment: If you consider the set up for large $N$ it is bound to be better to slice off the four corners and move them to the middle of the sides i.e. make the shape more circular.